# How can a file be opened while it is being downloaded onto sdcard and not when downloading to /data/data/packagename?

Tags: java, android

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
```

the same code when the path is /mnt/sdcard/aaa.png the image can be show. while the path is data/data/com.test/aaa.png the image can't be show.Does it need some permission.I have download it in the path.
the error is like

when parsing the image

```
09-12 11:54:31.448: ERROR/UriImage(545): got exception decoding bitmap 
09-12 11:54:31.448: ERROR/UriImage(545): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 11:54:31.448: ERROR/UriImage(545):     at com.android.camera.Util.makeInputStream(Util.java:336)
09-12 11:54:31.448: ERROR/UriImage(545):     at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:307)
09-12 11:54:31.448: ERROR/UriImage(545):     at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:299)
09-12 11:54:31.448: ERROR/UriImage(545):     at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:94)
09-12 11:54:31.448: ERROR/UriImage(545):     at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:86)
09-12 11:54:31.448: ERROR/UriImage(545):     at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.thumbBitmap(UriImage.java:120)
09-12 11:54:31.448: ERROR/UriImage(545):     at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.executeRequest(ImageGetter.java:173)
09-12 11:54:31.448: ERROR/UriImage(545):     at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.run(ImageGetter.java:149)
09-12 11:54:31.448: ERROR/UriImage(545):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
09-12 11:54:31.828: ERROR/UriImage(545): got exception decoding bitmap 
09-12 11:54:31.828: ERROR/UriImage(545): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 11:54:31.828: ERROR/UriImage(545):     at com.android.camera.Util.makeInputStream(Util.java:336)
09-12 11:54:31.828: ERROR/UriImage(545):     at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:307)
09-12 11:54:31.828: ERROR/UriImage(545):     at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:299)
09-12 11:54:31.828: ERROR/UriImage(545):     at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:94)
09-12 11:54:31.828: ERROR/UriImage(545):     at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.executeRequest(ImageGetter.java:204)
09-12 11:54:31.828: ERROR/UriImage(545):     at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.run(ImageGetter.java:149)
09-12 11:54:31.828: ERROR/UriImage(545):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

when parsing the apk file

```
09-12 12:01:41.307: WARN/PackageParser(1298): Skipping dir: /data/data/com.download.activity/files/aaa.apk

09-12 12:01:41.307: WARN/PackageInstaller(1298): Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set a permission to access the SD card?

Comment: the permission was added.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA" />

Comment: the code to open the file worked when I downloaded in sd,while it didn't work when download in data/data/mypackage/.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("file:///data/data/com.android.cab/files/TestApp1.apk")),"application/vnd.android.package-archive"); 
startActivity(intent); 

It gives Parse Error and Warning: 
WARN/PackageParser(241): Skipping dir: /file:/data/data/com.android.cab/files/TestApp1.apk 
WARN/PackageInstaller(241): Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation

Comment: This directory is exclusive for your application and thus can't be read by different applications. If you want to show the downloaded image, you have to either read and display it by yourself or copy it to a public directory such as the sd card.